# How to check that data is retrieve successfully from database in array $this->data['tips']?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to check that data is retrieve successfully from database in array $this->data['tips'] in codeigniter framework. i want to check this is controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$result = $this->db->get('table')->result_array();
```

in `$result` variable result array will be saved.
you can check the length of `$result` array.

Comment: how can i check the length of array ( $this->data['tips'] = $this->cookingtipsmodel->getTipsByCategory($category); ) retrieving data from database in model and checking length of array in controller

Comment: sizeof(); function return the length of array.

Comment: public function category($category)
 {
  $this->load->model('cookingtipsmodel');
  
  $this->data['tips'] = $this->cookingtipsmodel->getTipsByCategory($category);
  
  if($category == NULL){
   $this->load->view('cookingtips/index');
  }
  if(sizeof($this->data) < 1){
   $this->load->view('cookingtips/index');
  }
  
above is my function code in controller i want to check if 4

Comment: i want to check if $category is empty then redirect and if $this->data['tips'] is empty then redirect

Comment: public function category($category) {
 $this->load->model('cookingtipsmodel'); 
 
 if($category == NULL){ $this->load->view('cookingtips/index'); }
 else{
  $tips = $this->cookingtipsmodel->getTipsByCategory($category);
 if(sizeof($tips) < 1){ $this->load->view('cookingtips/index'); }
 }
}

try this